# How to add "description" for a column in Postgres DB using the corresponding Django model?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

For e.g., in this table, I'd like to be able add the "description" text at the Django ORM layer and have it reflected at the database level.

```
test=# \d+ django_model
              Table "public.django_model"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Description
--------+---------+-----------+-------------
 i      | integer |           |
 j      | integer |           |
Indexes:
    "mi" btree (i) - Tablespace: "testspace"
    "mj" btree (j)
Has OIDs: no
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can't do it. Here's the https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13867 request. Closed 6 ya as "Won't do".

You still can use postgres `COMMENT` extension, eg:

```
t=# create table t (i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 12.068 ms
t=# comment on column t.i is 'some description';
COMMENT
Time: 2.994 ms
t=# \d+ t
                                       Table "postgres.t"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target |   Description
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+------------------
 i      | integer |           |          |         | plain    |              | some description
 t      | text    |           |          |         | extended |              |
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I have found these links.
But, didn't make sense to separate out the information from models, because it might lead to maintenance overhead and potential discrepancies between what's there at the application vs database.

Comment: it seems `comment on database <db> is 'description';` is also possible, and the `is` keyword is required.